# How to get stack size and stack limit of any thread using Win32 API

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, stack

Is it possible to obtain the size and limit of the stack of ANY thread using the Win32 API? I know that this is possible for the current thread in the following way:

```
NT_TIB *tib = (NT_TIB*)NtCurrentTeb();
DWORD stackBase = (DWORD)tib->StackBase;
DWORD stackLimit = (DWORD) tib->StackLimit;
```

However, I haven't found a Win32 API function that returns the `NT_TIB` structure for any given thread HANDLE or TID as input parameter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're debugging the process, you can get the TIB/TEB address from the `lpThreadLocalBase` field in the [`CREATE_THREAD_DEBUG_INFO`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679287) structure.

Otherwise you'll have to rely on the semi-documented `NtQueryInformationThread` API. If you use the `ThreadBasicInformation` category, the returned [`THREAD_BASIC_INFORMATION` struct](http://undocumented.ntinternals.net/UserMode/Structures/THREAD_BASIC_INFORMATION.html) has a `TebBaseAddress` field.

Comment: Add: Also if my memory serves, KUSER_SHARED_DATA contains TEB address. Now upvote. :-)

Comment: If the thread is in another process, you will have to use `ReadProcessMemory()` to read the `TEB` that is located at `TebBaseAddress`.

Comment: I chose the second option and it works fine. Thanks!